# How to Append a Row in a Datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a datatable say dt1( which keeps changing its inside a loop). I have another datatable say dt2( initially its null). Now I have to append the Rows of dt1 in dt2. I tried using Merge(), but the previous rows of dt2 are vanishing. 
Any idea How to do this ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are clearing the `dt2` table everytime the loop runs. Try this:

```
DataTable dt1 = null; DataTable dt2 = null;

for (int i = 0; i < dt3.Rows.Count; i++) 
{

    // here  "strSQL" is build which changes on the "i" value                  

    dt1 = GetDataTable(strSQL); // this returns a table with single Row

    if(dt2 == null) 
    {
       dt2 = dt1.Clone();
    }

    dt2.Merge(dt1,true);
}
```

Also, if the query restriction based on `i` is applied to a primary key column you can use

```
dt2.ImportRow(dt1.Rows[0]);
```

instead of

```
dt2.Merge(dt1,true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, I see that you're using dt2 = dt1.Clone();
That's wiping all the contents in dt2, so you're only adding the current contents of dt1 to dt2.

Instead of cloning you should just merge the contents of dt1 to dt2.

Comment: For firstcase I'm getting error(Object reference not set to an instance of an object.).
And for dt2.Merge(dt1, true) the previous rows are getting deleted on subsequent merge function.

Comment: could you perhaps paste some code in your question so we can see what's happening? 'Cause my answer normally should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`ImportRow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.importrow.aspx) method, like this:

```
var table2 = new DataTable();

foreach(DataRow row in table1.Rows)
    table2.ImportRow(row);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another derivative to João Angelo's answer would be to initialize dt2 ahead of time and then you can remove the null check

```
DataTable dt1 = null; DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

for (int i = 0; i < dt3.Rows.Count; i++) 
{

    // here  "strSQL" is build which changes on the "i" value                  

    dt1 = GetDataTable(strSQL); // this returns a table with single Row

    dt2.Merge(dt1,true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
  DataRow[] rows = new DataRow[dt1.Rows.Count];
  dt1.Rows.CopyTo(rows, 0);
  foreach (DataRow row in rows)
  {
    dt2.Rows.Add(row);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm assuming your tables have the same structure

```
 foreach (DataRow row in dt1.Rows)
     dt2.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
```